# vlookup or match for a variable in source table which is a column header in target table

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

We have organized data outputs from SPSS in the following format. It has ID (based on concatenate) , Country, Species, Product and then the predictors followed by the respective coefficients.

[image]

In another worksheet I have the same format but the variables are now columns, so I want to bring the coefficients under each column from the previous table.

[image]

Thank you for the help

I tried using sumifs to match the IDs and then another criteria to match the column / variables but its definitely wrong. If I used vlookup, I'll need to create new columns for each Predictor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple INDEX/MATCH/MATCH will do it:

In K2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$O,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),MATCH(F2,Sheet2!$1:$1,0)),"")
```

Where Sheet2 is the sheet on which the values are located.

OFFSET and INDIRECT are volatile functions.  INDEX/MATCH is not.

Answer (score 1):

Enter into F2 of second worksheet (if your table starts on A1):

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Sheet1!$K2,,MATCH(Sheet2!F$1,OFFSET(Sheet1!$F2,,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F2:$J2)),0)-1),"")
```

- Sheet1!$K2 = field under Coefficient 1 in first worksheet (=10)
- Sheet2!F$1 = field above formula in second worksheet (=GDP)
- Sheet1!$F2 = field under Predictor 1 in first worksheet (=GDP)
- Sheet1!$F2:$J2 = all entries under the Predictors in first worksheet

Now drag it down and then over to the right.

---

A second approach based on Scott Craners suggestion (I cannot comment yet, but I understand your question slightly different then he does - credits go to him though):

Enter in Sheet2!F2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$K$2:$O$7,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Sheet2!F$1,Sheet1!$F2:$J2,0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, using `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$K:$O,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),MATCH(F$1,Sheet1!$F2:$J2,0)),"")` as suggested by Scott is giving me the right values but using `Sheet1!$K$2:$O$7` is giving me matches but wrong ones. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

**If you need smaller solution**, check this one pleas:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(F$1,Sheet1!$F2:$J2,0)+10)),"")
```

copy this formula in Destination Sheet F2, and Paste it on whole destination table as you know.

Suppose that your source data is in Sheet1 (if not, change "Sheet1!" to your source sheet name)

And the numbers are base on your image, for first 5 constants then 5 coefficients, and at last 5 value.

Comment: Thank you Armin, Really helpful and helped me understand this better!

Comment: glad to hear that.